# consumer producer communication from java to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a very common problem and believe me I am not able to find a apt solution over the internet .

**[problem]**:  Front end application

[image: current architecture]

Here in this current architecture I have tried using

**SNS**

But not able to figure out  do I send data to a particular logged in user from **Application A**

**SQS**

Same issue on how do I send data to a particular logged in user

**push notification**
That works for  every user but still it requires permission from browser  and a lot of other stuff

> I have also come up my own solution which became very complicated  but
> this is a very common problem and there is always a very good design
> for this I am sure but not able to figure out what it is?

The java application is spring boot

The middle one is Nodejs

The front end is JavaScript

Can some one give me some idea on how do I achieve this ,or if someone can guide me into a correct direction is much appreciated .

Thank you.

Comment: Is there anything asynchronous and long-running happening here? If this is just a synchronous call handle it like one, App A calls nodejs, waits for a response and sends that response to the user. Same thing for all other interactions. If it is in fact asynchronous there a lot of ways to achieve communication back to the client: web sockets for example, or let the user long-poll the server until the server actually response with something, ....

Comment: Hey @luk2302 thank you for responding , yes it is just asynchronous HTTP rest  calls  .User from **Application A**  submits form for another user from  **Application B** in random time .When user is logs  into **Application B**  he/she sees some data and to see any new data for that user ,we need to use web socket as you said but still . need it to be event driven like on a form submit  auto fetch for example user 33 in Application B